# Custom HTML Options Page but Access to Components like Add-on Manager Tab

Tags: firefox-addon

I have an add-on which has a custom options page. It's in HTML. I would like to give it full access to Components just like the Add-on Manager tab.

These are things I currently do which I don't like: Listen to page loads, if it's my options url then on load add event listeners.

I tried messing with my chrome.manifest file to heck and back I couldn't manage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML loaded from a `chrome://` URL will load the page with chrome privileges, e.g. `chrome://global/content/aboutMemory.xhtml`.

Just register a `content` package via `chrome.manifest`, if you haven't already, and you're done.

Comment: This stuff needs to be clearer on MDN. Mozilla should hire me for MDN.

Comment: Who'll teach you the difference between "u" and "you" first? :p

Comment: HAHAHAHAAH!! I do that a lot I kno :P